# Laravel После DDOS проблема с заходом не авторизованных пользователей

Tags: php, laravel, сессия, php-fpm

Всем привет! После DDOS атаки не грузит сайт для неавторизованных пользователей. Все авторизованные пользователи спокойной заходят на сайт и используют весь функционал сайта.(Готов заплатить за помощь)

Версии:
Laravel 9.2 - PHP 8.1.5 - NGINX

По моим исследованиям код стопорится в глобальном Middleware (\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class)

App\Http\Kernel.php:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        'throttle:api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
```

Если капнуть еще глубже и залезть в сам StartSession, то стоп строка это `$response = $next($request);`. После этой строчки сервер просто не дает ответа и получаем TimeOut

StartSession:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (! $this->sessionConfigured()) {
        return $next($request);
    }


    $session = $this->getSession($request);

    if ($this->manager->shouldBlock() ||
        ($request->route() instanceof Route && $request->route()->locksFor())) {
        return $this->handleRequestWhileBlocking($request, $session, $next);
    }

    return $this->handleStatefulRequest($request, $session, $next);
}

/**
 * Handle the given request within session state.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Session\Session  $session
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function handleStatefulRequest(Request $request, $session, Closure $next)
{
    // If a session driver has been configured, we will need to start the session here
    // so that the data is ready for an application. Note that the Laravel sessions
    // do not make use of PHP "native" sessions in any way since they are crappy.
    $request->setLaravelSession(
        $this->startSession($request, $session)
    );
    $this->collectGarbage($session);

    //ПОСЛЕ ЭТОЙ СТРОЧКИ TIMEOUT(бесконечная загрузка)
    $response = $next($request);

    
    $this->storeCurrentUrl($request, $session);

    $this->addCookieToResponse($response, $session);

    // Again, if the session has been configured we will need to close out the session
    // so that the attributes may be persisted to some storage medium. We will also
    // add the session identifier cookie to the application response headers now.
    $this->saveSession($request);

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Смотрите логи NGINX - error.log, либо в storage/logs/laravel-DD-MM-YY.log

Comment: Место на диске есть? `df -h`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблемы была совсем в другом ) Не синхронный апи который блокировался при большой аудитории)